# Running a Python Script every n Days in Django App

Tags: python, django

I am looking to run a Python script every `n` days as part of a Django app.

I need this script to add new rows to the database for each attribute that a user has.

For example a `User` has many `Site`s each that have multiple `Metric` data points. I need to add a new `Metric` data point for each `Site` every `n` days by running a .py script.

I have already written the script itself, but it just works locally.

Is it the right approach to:

1) Get something like Celery or just a simple cron task running to run the python script every `n` days.

2) Have the python script run through all the `Metric`s for each `Site` and add a new data point by executing a SQL command from the python script itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Django's manage commad](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/), then use **crontab** to run this command circularly.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to write the script - which you have already done. This script should run the task which is to be repeated.

The second step is to schedule the execution.

The de-facto way of doing that is to write a cron entry for the script. This will let the system's cron daemon trigger the script at the interval you select.

To do so, create an entry in the crontab file for the user that owns the script; the command to do so is `crontab -e`, which will load a plain text file in your preferred editor.

Next, you need to add an entry to this file. The format is:

```
minutes hours day-of-month month day-of-week script-to-execute
```

So if you want to run your script every 5 days:

```
0 0 */5 * * /bin/bash /home/user/path/to/python.py
```